# Which opset version is supported by torch.oonnx

Tags: python, pytorch, onnx

Im trying to export the SPIGA model to .onnx format. My code to do so is the following:

```
# Create three dummy tensors with the specified sizes
    input_image = torch.randn(1, 3, 256, 256).cuda()  # Size: (batch_size, channels, height, width)
    landmarks = torch.randn(1, 98, 3).cuda()  # Size: (batch_size, num_landmarks, 3)
    cam_matrix = torch.randn(1, 3, 3).cuda()  # Size: (batch_size, 3, 3)

    # Create a list containing these tensors
    dummy_input = [input_image, landmarks, cam_matrix]
    #dummy_input = ([torch.randn(1, 3, 256, 256).cuda(), self.model3d, self.cam_matrix])
    onnx_model_path = "spiga_model.onnx"  # Output ONNX file path
    torch.onnx.export(
        self.model,  # Y/our SPIGA model instance
        dummy_input,  # Example input data
        onnx_model_path,  # Output ONNX file path
        verbose=True,  # Enable verbose mode for debugging (optional)
        input_names=self.model_inputs,  # List of input names (adjust as needed)
        output_names=["features"],  # List of output names (adjust as needed)
        opset_version=14  # ONNX opset version (adjust as needed)
    )

    print(f"SPIGA model exported to {onnx_model_path}")
```

From what i could read from the documentation the opset version should be between 9 and 16. I have tried versio 7 to 20 and it tells me that none of these are supported.

Im using pycharm and this is my pytorch version:
Version: 2.0.1+cu117

and my torchvision version is:
Version: 0.15.2+cu117.

The error code im getting from pycharm is: Exporting the operator 'aten::affine_grid_generator' to ONNX opset version 14 is not supported. Please feel free to request support or submit a pull request on PyTorch GitHub: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues.
its the same error message I get with all the opset versions i have tried.

Comment: For clarification, did you export as 14 and try and load with opsets from 7 to 20 or did you export the model with opset versions from 7 to 20 and try and load them using identical opset version?

Comment: Im trying to export it but everytime no matter which opset_version I'm trying I get the error mentioned above

Comment: Have you tried downgrading pytorch to something like 1.13.1 and exporting it to a lower opset number?

Comment: no I havent tried that. I used pip to install pytorch supporting cuda, and I'm not sure on how to downgrade pytorch so it still supports cuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was with the **torch.nn.functional.affine_grid** operator. Therefore I implemented the following code found from this post: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/30563

the code used is:

```
def affine_grid(theta, size, align_corners=False):
    N, C, H, W = size
    grid = create_grid(N, C, H, W)
    grid = grid.view(N, H * W, 3).bmm(theta.transpose(1, 2))
    grid = grid.view(N, H, W, 2)
    return grid

def create_grid(N, C, H, W):
    grid = torch.empty((N, H, W, 3), dtype=torch.float32).cuda()
    grid.select(-1, 0).copy_(linspace_from_neg_one(W))
    grid.select(-1, 1).copy_(linspace_from_neg_one(H).unsqueeze_(-1))
    grid.select(-1, 2).fill_(1)
    return grid

def linspace_from_neg_one(num_steps, dtype=torch.float32):
    r = torch.linspace(-1, 1, num_steps, dtype=torch.float32)
    r = r * (num_steps - 1) / num_steps
    return r
```

This fixed my issue and let me export my model to .onnx format

Answer (score 1):

[According to the documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/onnx_supported_aten_ops.html), TorchScript to ONNX conversion for `aten::affine_grid_generator` is not yet supported, so changing the opset will not resolve the issue.  This means that either

1. ONNX does not have an implementation for this operator, or
2. TorchScript to ONNX converter in `pytorch` does not yet have a mapping for it.

[ONNX docs](https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/main/docs/Operators.md#AffineGrid) reveal that in this case the latter scenario holds, as `AffineGrid` is supported since opset 20.

[Comments in this github issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/30563#issuecomment-1706815343) suggest two solutions. Apparently the operator can be successfully exported in torch 2.0 using `torch.onnx.dynamo_export`. Alternatively, [you could rewrite](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/30563#issuecomment-1295761759) `affine_grid` (or `grid_sample`) using other, more common functions.

If neither one work out, you will have to implement the support yourself. [Torch ONNX documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/onnx.html#adding-support-for-operators) has a nifty guide on how to do this for existing ONNX operators.

Comment: I have been looking a bit into it. It appears that i don't have the symbolic_opset20.py file. Is there a way that i can get it? I also tried the torch.onnx.dynamo_export but it told me that it doesnt exist.